# DevExpress GridView throwing exception when asigning to FocusedRowHandle

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress.XtraGrid GridView for WinForms, and I don't know why the code bellow is throwing this exception:

> An exception of type 'DevExpress.Utils.HideException' occurred in
>   DevExpress.XtraEditors.v13.1.dll but was not handled in user code

Stack Trace:

> at DevExpress.XtraEditors.Container.ContainerHelper.OnInvalidValueException(IWin32Window owner, Exception sourceException, Object fValue)
>   at DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.SetRowCellValueCore(Int32 rowHandle, GridColumn column, Object _value, Boolean fromEditor)
>   at DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.SetRowCellValueCore(Int32 rowHandle, GridColumn column, Object _value, Boolean fromEditor)
>   at DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.PostEditor(Boolean causeValidation)
>   at DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.BaseView.CloseEditor(Boolean causeValidation)
>   at DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.CheckCanLeaveRow(Int32 currentRowHandle, Boolean raiseUpdateCurrentRow)
>   at DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.DoChangeFocusedRow(Int32 currentRowHandle, Int32 newRowHandle, Boolean raiseUpdateCurrentRow)
>   at DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.DoChangeFocusedRowInternal(Int32 newRowHandle, Boolean updateCurrentRow)
>   at DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.set_FocusedRowHandle(Int32 value)
>   at xyzForm.gridView_MouseDown(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e) in c:...xyzForm.cs:line 1218
>   at DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.BaseView.RaiseMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
>   at DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.Handler.BaseViewHandler.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
>   at DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.Handler.GridHandler.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs ev)
>   at DevExpress.Utils.Controls.BaseHandler.ProcessEvent(EventType etype, Object args)
>   at DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.Handler.BaseViewHandler.ProcessEvent(EventType etype, Object args)
>   at DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs ev)

Code (simplified):

```
private void gridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    GridHitInfo info = gridView.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);

    if (info.Column == null) return;

    gridView.FocusedRowHandle = info.RowHandle; // this line throws
    gridView.FocusedColumn = info.Column;
}
```

Here `gridView.FocusedRowHandle` is an int (currently with value 4), and `info.RowHandle` is an int also (with value 5). The GridView has 20 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, GridControl throws this exception when you are trying to change a focused row while editor validation is not complete, because GridControl does not allow any actions until a correct value is entered in the validating editor. And it is not needed to do something with this exception in user code because this exception should be processed by GridControl itself and not affect your application.
I believe you should contact the [DevExpress Support](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) team directly to clarify the situation.